# Is it a bad idea to use something other than a string constant as an action type in redux?

Tags: redux

For example, using a `new String` wrapper to prevent name clashes:

```
// actions/forms/types.js
export const SUBMIT = new String('SUBMIT');

// actions/tabs/types.js
export const SUBMIT = new String('SUBMIT');
```

Thus, when writing a reducer ...

```
// reducers/forms.js
import { SUBMIT as FORM_SUBMIT } from '../actions/forms/types.js'
import { SUBMIT as TAB_SUBMIT } from '../actions/tabs/types.js'

console.log(FORM_SUBMIT === TAB_SUBMIT); // false;
export default function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FORM_SUBMIT:
      // correctly handle only FORM_SUBMIT, and not TAB_SUBMIT
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Would there be any downside to this? Or is this a good idea? Can't find much against it or for it

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not a good idea, on a couple levels.

Redux itself doesn't actually care what the value of `action.type` is - it only enforces that `action.type` is defined.  From there, how your reducer logic makes decisions is up to you.

I actually wasn't familiar with the use of `new String()` to produce non-equal references, so I had to look that one up.  Yes, that appears to produce valid differentiating comparisons, per this example:

```js
const a = new String("abcd");
const b = new String("abcd");
const c = "abcd";
const d = "abcd";

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case a: {
        console.log("a");
        break;
      }
      case b: {
        console.log("b");
        break;
      }
      case c: {
        console.log("c");
        break;
      }
      case d: {
        console.log("d");
        break;
      } 
    }
}

reducer(undefined, {type : a});
reducer(undefined, {type : b});
reducer(undefined, {type : "abcd"});
```

**HOWEVER**... if you attempt to log these actions, and or view the action history in the Redux DevTools, you are not going to be able to tell the difference between them visually.  The overall intent of Redux is to make it straightforward to track down what actions have been dispatched and when.  As a developer, there's lots of ways you can subvert that intent, but you're just going to be making things harder on yourself.

As for things *other* than strings, such as numbers or Symbols, those are also bad ideas.  Numbers aren't as readable in the action history as strings are, and Symbols are not serializable and will cause problems with debugging.  (Also see the [Redux FAQ entry on why actions should be serializable](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-string-constants).

I'm currently working on a blog post that will discuss the actual technical limitations that Redux requires (and why), vs how Redux is *intended* to be used, vs how it's *possible* to use Redux.  I'm currently aiming to have that post up early next week.  If you're interested, keep an eye on my blog at http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com .